# argument "" is missing, with no default when using map_dfc in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary, arguments, montecarlo

I am trying to modify Monte Carlo code from *Reproduceable Finance with R* to handle withdrawals and inflation of these withdrawals.

to do so I have changed a simulation accumulate function to subtract a withdrawl amount that has been increased do to inflation prior to calling the function.

```
 simulation_accum_withdrawls <- function(init_value, N, mean, stdev, wAmt) {
    tibble(c(init_value, 1 + rnorm(N, mean, stdev),wAmt)) %>% 
    `colnames<-`("returns") %>%
    mutate(growth = 
             accumulate(returns, function(x, y, wAmt) x * y - wAmt)) %>% 
    select(growth)
  }
```

the function is run from the following code

```
monte_carlo_sim <-
    map_dfc(starts, simulation_accum_withdrawls, 
      N = sim_duration_months, 
      mean = geo_mean_port_return, 
      stdev = geo_stddev_port_return,
      wAmt = inflated_withdrawls)
```

which throws off the following error.

> Error in `map()`:
> ℹ In index: 1.
> Caused by error in `mutate()`:
> ! Problem while computing `growth = accumulate(returns, function(x, y, wAmt) x * y - wAmt)`.
> Caused by error in `fn()`:
> ! argument "wAmt" is missing, with no default
> Backtrace:
>
> 1. purrr::map_dfc(...)
> 2. purrr::accumulate(returns, function(x, y, wAmt) x * y - wAmt)
> 3. purrr:::reduce_impl(...)
> 4. fn(out, elt, ...)
>    Error in map(.x, .f, ...) :

The inflated_withdrawls data frame does exist and is not empty i.e. see below

```
str(inflated_withdrawls)
'data.frame':   38 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ wAmt: num  1805391 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Any advice or insight on how to debug this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is an executable example per the request.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(broom)
library(highcharter)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)
library(readxl)

accum_inflation <- function(init_value, inflation=0.0) {
    tibble(c(init_value, 1 + inflation)) %>% 
    `colnames<-`("acc_inf") %>%
    mutate(acc_inf = 
             accumulate(acc_inf, function(x, y) x * y ))
}

accum_wd <- function(wAmt, acc_inf=0.0) {
     growth =  wAmt * acc_inf 
}

simulation_accum_1 <- function(init_value, N, mean, stdev,inf_wd) {
    tibble(c(init_value, 1 + rnorm(N, mean, stdev), inf_wd)) %>% 
    `colnames<-`("returns") %>%
    mutate(growth = 
             accumulate(returns, function(x, y) x * y - inf_wd)) %>% 
    select(growth)
}
  simulation_accum_withdrawls <- function(init_value, N, mean, stdev, wAmt=0) {
    tibble(c(init_value, 1 + rnorm(N, mean, stdev),wAmt)) %>% 
    `colnames<-`("returns") %>%
    mutate(growth = 
             accumulate(returns, function(x, y, wAmt) x * y + wAmt)) %>% 
    select(growth)
  }


test_df <- data.frame(wAmt =c(100000,-180000,-180000,-180000), 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2024-01-01"), by = "year", length.out = 4)
)

test_df <- test_df %>% pad_by_time(date, .by = "month", .pad_value = 0) 

inf_df <- rnorm(nrow(test_df),0.03/12,0.042/12)

inflated_returns <- accum_inflation(1, inf_df)
edatep1 <- ymd(edate)+months(1)
test_df<- rows_append(test_df,tibble(wAmt = 0, date = edatep1))
inflated_withdrawls <- accum_wd(test_df[1], inflated_returns)

nav=1000000
sim_duration_months = 40
total_sims = 10
geo_mean_port_return = 0.00443402454379282
geo_stddev_port_return = 0.0237813751473552
sims <- total_sims
starts <- 
 rep(nav, sims) %>%
 set_names(paste("sim", 1:sims, sep = ""))

monte_carlo_sim <-
    map_dfc(starts, simulation_accum_withdrawls, 
      N = sim_duration_months, 
      mean = geo_mean_port_return, 
      stdev = geo_stddev_port_return,
      wAmt = inflated_withdrawls)
```

Comment: It'd be easier to run and troubleshoot if the question were fully reproducible. Can you give small working examples of `starts` and the other starting conditions. (FYI, `tibble(c(..)) %>% \`colnames<-\`("results")` can be simplified greatly to `tibble(results=c(..))`.)

Comment: # This is the setup chunk 
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(broom)
library(highcharter)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)
library(readxl)

Comment: # This is the setup chunk 
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
library(tidyquant)
library(timetk)
library(broom)
library(highcharter)
library(purrr)
library(knitr)
library(readxl)